# Get all classes referenced by a class

Tags: java

Let's say I have a java.lang.Class instance, c at runtime.

At runtime, is there anyway to see what classes are used by c? e.g. if c.foo instantiates a B, B is being 'used'.  if c.foo calls static method G.bar(), G is being used.

Note: Only trying to get what classes could be known statically - I'm fine missing ones loaded by reflection.

In python, equivalent functionality is found in modulefinder:
http://docs.python.org/library/modulefinder.html

Comment: some class can be loaded dynamically, Use [`getLoadedClasses()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html#getAllLoadedClasses%28%29)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything that happens *outside* of method bodies, constructors and static initilizers can be queried with reflection. You can look at field and method signatures and reflect the fields to get the actual classes of field values.

Classes *used* inside methods are quite a challenge. You *could* use `BCEL` or a similiar tool to analyse the class file and extract all classnames that are *hardcoded* in the class file. But this will fail as soon as you program against interfaces:

```
public List someMethod() {
  return SomeClass.getList();
}
```

The type of the class returned by `someMethod` is not known by the class file. And there ist no lookup table or central registry. The JVM will know the type, look if the class is already loaded and - if not - try to load it. It doesn't have to care about *which* class asked for that other class and it will not record this information. Just because it is not needed for exectution and not needed for garbage collection.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, it is impossible because other referenced classes may be instantiated using reflection. Or they can be injected using dependency injection mechanism.

Comment: Good point. Reclarified as ignoring classes referenced via reflection.

Answer (score 1):

some class can be loaded dynamically, Use [`getLoadedClasses()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html#getAllLoadedClasses%28%29)

Comment: Useful, but that can only be done under constrained conditions. i.e. in my main(), I spawn c and nothing else exists.

Comment: Hmm, anyway to do this without requiring -agent at the command line?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this [Java Dependency Resolver project](http://code.google.com/p/java-dependency-resolver/) Which will find the not only the referenced classes and  jars as well for a particular class in a Project.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Maven Dependency Analyzer](http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-dependency-analyzer/) and its class [ASMDependencyAnalyzer](https://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-dependency-analyzer/apidocs/org/apache/maven/shared/dependency/analyzer/asm/ASMDependencyAnalyzer.html):

```
Set<String> referencedClasses = new ASMDependencyAnalyzer().analyze(new File("ClassName.class").toURI().toURL())
```

Answer (score 1):

One could use `javap -v ClassFile.class` and inspect the outcome.
The constant pool contains the VM names of all used classes and interface references either as e.g. Class or Methodref etc.
It is a file system op (creating e.g. temp files, reading the class and or jar file) and will not perform very well, but can be used to investigate a reference class for non-functionals aspect using relatively simple regex. You could for instance check if unallowed classes etc are indeed not used.

```
Constant pool:
#1 = InterfaceMethodref #263.#264     // appointmentplanner/api/Time.asMinutes:()I
#2 = Methodref          #105.#265     // appointmentplanner/APDayPlan."<init>":(Ljava/time/LocalDate;II)V
#3 = Methodref          #115.#266     // java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
#4 = Fieldref           #105.#267     // appointmentplanner/APDayPlan.date:Ljava/time/LocalDate;
#5 = Class              #268          // appointmentplanner/LinearAllocator
#6 = Methodref          #5.#269       // appointmentplanner/LinearAllocator."<init>":(II)V
#7 = Fieldref           #105.#270     // appointmentplanner/APDayPlan.allocator:Lappointmentplanner/LinearAllocator;
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at the [Heap functions available in the JVM Tool Interface](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/platform/jvmti/jvmti.html#Heap) which allow you to iterate through the heap and recursively follow object references. It will require a lot of work to use this though.